# R Plotly Sankey - link with same soure and target looks like broken, and even color is different when large dataset

Tags: plotly, sankey-diagram

1. I have some user behavior data, and convert the raw data into source, target and value format, in order to draw a sankey chart of user behavior flow, and then displayed and filtered in powerBI.

raw data contains below columns:

2. Below is a piece of sample data after converting. I want a sankey chart that could be filtered by dataCenter, customer and companyID in powerBI.

3.Then I draw sankey chart by R plotly script

```
library("plotly")
a = read.csv('testSankey.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
node_names <- unique(c(as.character(a$source), as.character(a$target)))
node_names <- node_names[order(sub('.*_', '', node_names))]
nodes <- data.frame(name = node_names)
links <- data.frame(source = match(a$source, node_names) - 1,
                    target = match(a$target, node_names) - 1,
                    value = a$value)

definePosition <- function(nodeList){
  #  nodeList = node_names
  # unique name endings
  endings = unique(sub('.*_', '', nodeList))
  # define intervals
  steps = 1/length(endings)
  # x-values for each unique name ending
  # for input as node position
  nodes_x = {}
  xVal = 0
  for (e in endings) {
    nodes_x[e] = xVal
    xVal = xVal + steps
    
  }
  # x and y values in list form
  x_values <- 0
  y_values <- 0
  i =1
  for (n in nodeList) {
    last = sub('.*_', '', n)
    x_values[i] = nodes_x[last]
    y_values[i] = 0.001 * length(x_values)
    i = i + 1
  }
  
  return(list(x_values, y_values))
  
}

position = definePosition(node_names)
node_x = position[[1L]]
node_y = position[[2L]]

#Plot
plot_ly(type='sankey',
             orientation = "h",
             arrangement = "snap",
             node = list (
               label = node_names,
               x = node_x,
               y = node_y,
               color = "grey",
               pad = 15,
               thinkness = 15,
               line = list(color = "grey", width = 0.5)),
               link = list(source = links$source, target = links$target, value = links$value))
```

After I ran above script. I found that the links for the same source and target are not smoothly, and even the color is different. I guess this is because the whole link for the source and target are returned by many many different values(sub-links).

I am trying to fix this issue by find a solution with google, and couldn't find a correct solution. By the way, I tried with smaller dataset, there's no issue and the link color looks normal.

can the expert please help? Is there any workaround or way to avoid this UI issue?

Answer (score 0):

i found this issue has gone by specifying a link color instead of using the default color. this way is a little tricky, anyway, the links looks like normal now when there's large dataset to plot.

```
p <- sankeyNetwork(Links = links, Nodes = nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              fontSize = 9,
              fontFamily = "sans-serif", nodePadding=10,
              margin = list(t=100),
              sinksRight = FALSE, iterations = 0,
              LinkGroup = "linkgroup", 
              colourScale = colourScale)
```